# No actionBar with app-compat-v21 library in preferenceactivity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm having problem with ActionBar and app-compat-v21. 
ActionBar is shown everywhere except `PreferenceActivity` 
I tried to follow recommendations and made it with Fragments:

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
 }
}
```

and

```
public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).commit();
 }
}
```

However, there's no ActionBar. 
BTW, in `Styles.xml` is set `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

What's wrong?

Comment: Oh, really? [look at the picture](http://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/androidpreferenceactivity/screenshots/example-wizard-smartphone-v2.0.0.png)

Comment: `PreferenceActivity` is deprecated in favor of `PreferenceFragment`. So, your settings screen should be a `PreferenceFragment` hosted by an `ActionBarActivity` from AppCompat library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the new appcompat v21 you have to:

- extend the `AppCompatActivity`
- use a theme which inherits from *Theme.AppCompat*.(for example Light or NoActionBar)

The `PreferenceActivity` **doesn't extend** the `AppCompatActivity`.

It is the reason why there is no actionbar in your code.

As solution you can create a PreferenceFragment as you are doing and **use it** in a standard **AppCompatActivity**.

**UPDATED 12/06/2015**

With the new 22.1+ appcompat you can use also the [AppCompatDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html) to extend AppCompat's support to any Activity.

You can check this official link to [AppCompatPreferenceActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java), where you can find an example of this technique.

Comment: So, I just need to extend ActionBarActivity and make it look like PreferenceActivity by myself, right?

Comment: Could you link me to an example? Can't find anything suitable

Comment: There is no `ActionBar` for Preference even if you extend `ActionBarActivity`. You will have to use a `toolbar`.

Comment: @donniezazen it depends by your style. Of course you can use a Toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

With the app compat the toolbar needs to be defined in the layout. You can create a layout for the Settings Activity with the toolbar and then add the preference fragment.

For example:

activity_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settings_fragment"
        android:name="com.bla.bla.MyPreferenceFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SettingsActivity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        Toolbar actionbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        actionbar.setTitle("Settings");
        actionbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SettingsActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

MyPreferenceFragment:

```
public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);;
    }
}
```

edit: Updated the answer to use ActionBarActivity instead of the deprecated PreferenceActivity

Comment: What is "Fragment" section in XML for? Where can I describe settings (like in preferences.xml)?

Comment: Hi. I've update my answer with an example of PreferenceFragment where you load all the preferences from the xml file. The fragment section in the xml is to load a fragment directly to the layout without having to call the fragmentManager transaction from the code (You can do it with a framelayout as a fragment container also).